# How to install and use Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

I need for a project to use Google Chrome on my Raspberry Pi 3.
I read a lot of articles that says it's impossible.
And others wich propose to install [ExaGear Desktop](https://eltechs.com/product/exagear-desktop/), but it's not free :/
I tryed to install [Chromium OS](https://flintos.io) to install Chrome on it : Doesn't work.
I tryed to install [pi64](https://github.com/bamarni/pi64) to install Chrome on it : Doesn't work.

Please don't say me : "Try Chromium !", or "Use Iceweasel, it's better".

I never tryed to emulate an other OS like a Windows, or anything else. Do you know a trick, even dirty, to launch Google Chrome on Raspberry PI 3 ? Even if the performances are bad.

I'm searching for multiple months ... Thanks :)

Comment: There's no version of chrome currently available for pi. Chromium is as close as you'll get for now without all the emulation solutions like exagear which you mentioned. Why exactly do you specifically need chrome on a pi??

Comment: I need to use the SpeechToText functionality for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This Youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sBslh3nWu0U) is a solution I found.
It will install Windows 10 ARM on your Raspberry PI.
It's slow, but if you stay in the same Chrome web page, It can work.

Comment: Not the prettiest solution but it is the actual Chrome.